# Loss of Mouse Function and Notebook Control in Vers. 12.3

Tags: notebooks

Since upgrading to Windows 11, Ver. 12.3 seems to be performing oddly on my machine and wonder if others are experiencing unexpected problems.

In trying to follow along on a WRI channel video (Deploying Reports and Results with Wolfram Notebooks Abrita Chakravarty), I create a new scratch notebook as suggested (and saving it as a named file).  I then proceed, following the video, to create the entity South American COUNTRIES via the alpha interpreter and then subsequently issue the following command:

```
 populationGDP = EntityValue [(*south American countries entity that appears within an 
     entity dialog box*), {"Population", "GDP"}, "EntityAssociation"]
```

exactly as given in the video.  Upon hitting Shift-Enter, Mathematica displays the interpreted result for each of the 14 countries, exactly as given in the video without error.

Unfortunately, something else also happens as a result:  I then lose the ability to place the mouse cursor within the open notebook, making it impossible to either save the result/notebook, scroll to see the full list, or use any entries or subentries of the notebook menu bar (ie "File", "Edit", "Format" ... "Help".  The cursor vanishes within the notebook, thus Mathematica seems "freeze up", forcing shutting down the process via the Windows task manager and restarting Mathematica.  The mouse remains working elsewhere on my dual screen set up and in other processes, however not within the notebook window.  Pressing any key with the mouse seemingly moved within the displayed notebook (but not visible) fails to return normal control of the notebook or a visible mouse within any open notebook window.

If leave the uncontrolled notebook open, move to the mathematica icon on the Windows toolbar and open a different notebook, it opens the other notebook, but it too has become non-functional (although in this case, the mouse can be seen and moved within the notebook window until I depress a mouse button).  Otherwise, depressing a mouse buttons has no effect and the other notebook can not be further controlled/executed/edited/minimized/closed/saved, etc.) once a mousekey is depressed.

If I open another notebook first (with all working fine) and then try to recreate the "video" notebook both notebooks fail to work (ie mouse not visible and cursor and mouse function/focus lost until I kill the frontend via the Windows task manager, since I no longer can do it from within the notebook window or via the standard windows contols ("minimize","maximize" or "exit").  Nor can the command above be saved once executed using ^S.  It would seem that after the command above is issued, loss of mouse focus within any open notebook occurs.

Oddly, as I type this question, I see the scrollbar in the offending notebook flickering slightly as if moving down and then back, but without any apparent movement of the contents.  However, the notebook scrollbar remains non-functional.

I am running Ver. 12.3 on a Windows 11 Pro - 64-bit platform.

**Is anyone else experiencing a similar issue?**

I note that in a previous stack-exchange question, some unexpected mouse behavior has been reported for version 12.3 (Question 246400), but without rendering Mathematica 12.3 completely non-functional as being experienced here.  If I kill Mathematica and then start with any previously saved notebook, all seems normal so it would seem that something within the notebook I have created to follow along with the video is causing the problem.  Since no errors are reported, I am perplexed as to what is happening here or what to do about it.  Suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: I've heard of similar things happening in 12.3.0, not in 12.3.1 though.  Which exact version are you using?  `SystemInformation["Small"]` would be helpful.

Comment: Version 12.3.0.0.  {"Kernel" -> {"SystemID" -> "Windows-x86-64", 
   "ReleaseID" -> "12.3.0.0 (7304197, 202105107768)", 
   "CreationDate" -> 
    DateObject[{2021, 5, 10, 19, 59, 45}, "Instant", 
     "Gregorian", -8.]}, 
 "FrontEnd" -> {"OperatingSystem" -> "Windows", 
   "ReleaseID" -> "12.3.0.0 (7304197, 202105113684)", 
   "CreationDate" -> 
    DateObject[{2021, 5, 11, 13, 18, 44}, "Instant", 
     "Gregorian", -8.]}}

Comment: I would update to 12.3.1 and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Upgrading to 12.3.1 has in fact resolved the problem, but not sure why the error showed up in 12.3.0.